# Как удалить поддержку JavaScript из проекта Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

В меню `PHP` проекта имеется меню конвертации например в `Tern` или `JavaScript` проект.
Но меню для обратного преобразования нету, или оно всетаки где то имеется?

Comment: Как вопрос связан с темой?

Comment: @Qwertiy Если честно то я не совсем понял ваш вопрос... С темой или тегом Eclipse? Что непонятного в вопросе?